# What is the runtime complexity if T(n)= n*T(n-1)?

Tags: runtime, asymptotic-complexity

Should I use a tree to solve this ? Or is there an easiest way to solve it?
I think it is n! right?

Thank you.

Comment: This is probably better asked on [cs.se]

Comment: it is e^(n*ln(n) - n)

Comment: What is the best case?

Answer (score 3):

Using recurrence relations, you may do this:

[image]